# Reset Model Value On Cascaded DropDown Change

Tags: angularjs, cascadingdropdown

I have two drop downs .One to show departments and other to show sections on change of department .

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="cascaded as cas">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="select-department" class="control-label col-md-2">Department</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="select-department" class="form-control" name="department" ng-model="myModel.department"
                ng-options="option.name for option in departments track by option.id">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>

        <label for="select-department" class="control-label col-md-2">Section</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select id="select-section" class="form-control" name="section" ng-model="myModel.section"
                    ng-options="option.name for option in sections track by option.id">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
            {{myModel.section}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine for me . If I change department all respective section gets updated and if I select any section respective section also gets assigned to the model . But the problem is if second time I change my department value, section drop down gets updated the model value doesn't reset to blank . It still shows the last selected value .

```
    var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);

angular.module("mainApp").controller("cascaded", function ($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.departments = [
    {
        id: 1, name: "Dep A"
    }, {
        id: 2, name: "Dep B"
    }, {
        id: 3, name: "Dep C"
    }];

    var sections = [
    {
        id: 1, name: "Sec A", parentId: 1
    }, {
        id: 2, name: "Sec B", parentId: 2
    }, {
        id: 3, name: "Sec C", parentId: 3
    }];

    $scope.$watch("myModel.department", function (newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            $scope.sections = $filter("filter")(sections, { parentId: newVal.id });
        }

    });

})
```

I want to reset my model value when section drop down gets refreshed with new data .

Comment: Can you apply it on fiddler?

Comment: below is the fiddle link .https://jsfiddle.net/opgcxLrx/

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the sections value to your `mymodel.section` value

```
 $scope.myModel.section= $scope.sections;
```

Because `$scope.myModel.section` is does not update, when you changing the department,

Your watch event should be

```
  $scope.$watch("myModel.department", function (newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            $scope.sections = $filter("filter")(sections, { parentId: newVal.id });
            **$scope.myModel.section= $scope.sections;**
        }

    });
```

[Fiddler Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/opgcxLrx/2/)

Comment: You have assigned the complete array of sections to section model . I am not sure about this . Can you please help me to find out the root cause why my model is not updating ..

Answer (score 0):

Simply put one method in ng-change of department like:

```
 <select id="select-department" class="form-control" name="department" ng-model="myModel.department"
                ng-options="option.name for option in departments track by option.id" ng-change="setBlank()">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
```

And in the method `setBlank()` set `myModel.section` to blank like this:

```
$scope.setBlank=function(){
  $scope.myModel.section='';
}
```

Comment: I can not set it's value to blank as I am using the same form for edit as well . So next time user comes for edit section will be set to blank when I set the selected department  . I just want to know why respective $scope is not getting updated  with new drop down data .Why it's holding the old reference where as I have new records in my drop down . I tried to use $apply but that's not working here as it throws $digets is in progress error .